# How can get information about sport in Germany from dbpedia using SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

How can I get information about sports in Germany from DBpedia using SPARQL? What SPARQL query can get that information? I used this SPARQL query, but I get no results!

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?c a dbpedia.org/ontology/Country . 
  ?c rdfs:label dbpedia:Germany .
}
```

Comment: i tried   
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?c a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> .
   ?c rdfs:label dbpedia:Germany
}   but i didn't get any result !

Comment: Jack, can you edit you question to include the query you are using? The question will be more complete this way and will be much more likely to get the attention of someone knowledgeable.

Comment: How comfortable are you in working with SPARQL and DBpedia?  Some [other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16721026/1281433) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17221869/1281433) have answers that discuss getting started with SPARQL, finding out what properties are available, browsing the data in a web browser, and so on. There's a Wikipedia article called [Sport in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport_in_Germany), and a [corresponding DBpedia resource](http://dbpedia.org/page/Sport_in_Germany).  Browsing the latter will help you determine what to query for.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fixing the Query

The query you posted is malformed.  Attempting to run it on the public DBpedia SPARQL endpoint produces an error.  The reference `dbpedia.org/ontology/Country` should be `dbpedia-owl:Country`, and `rdfs:label`s are usually strings, so `"Germany"@en` should replace `dbpedia:Germany`.  The corrected query, however, just returns a single result, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany.

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?c a dbpedia-owl:Country . 
  ?c rdfs:label "Germany"@en .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%2a+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fc+a+dbpedia-owl%3ACountry+.+%0D%0A++%3Fc+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Germany%22%40en+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

#### Asking about sport in Germany

Without more information about what kind of data you're trying to obtain, the simplest answer for querying about sport in Germany is that you should ask DBpedia to describe sport in Germany for you, almost literally.  The following query is legal SPARQL that you can paste into the [public DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
describe dbpedia:Sport_in_Germany
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+dbpedia%3ASport_in_Germany&format=text%2Fturtle&timeout=30000&debug=on)

There is a Wikipedia article [Sport in Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport_in_Germany), and [DBpedia's naming convention](http://dbpedia.org/Datasets#h18-4) is such that there is a corresponding DBpedia resource, [dbpedia:Sport_in_Germany](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sport_in_Germany), which the previous query describes.